# Spring Batch - max workers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

We have a Spring Batch application that creates workers on the Cloud as separate pods. We are throttling the max number of workers that can be created in parallel using the batch.max.workers property. However, additional workers are not getting created after these are Completed.

For example, if we have a scenario where 10000 records are to be processed, with a partition size of 1000, then we need 10 workers. But considering resource usage limits, we are throttling this to 5 pods at a time. So when the first 5 pods come up and get Completed, the job remains pending (Master job does not give status Completed) and the remaining 5 pods don't get created at all.
Is there some other property we should set for this?

We are using Spring Boot 2.1.9.

Comment: Can you share more details about your setup? Are you using the `DeployerPartitionHandler`? It should be possible to have more partitions than workers, but we need to know more about how workers are designed and who is managing their lifecylce.

Comment: Thanks, it ended up working fine. I believe we had some configuration errors earlier in the cluster. It automatically corrected. Thanks!